# How to lock the Firefox address bar on English Keyboard?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, address-bar

I'm using two different keyboard languages on my Windows 7 and sometimes I switch between them. I'd like to know why the address bar textbox allows different languages while the internet domain addresses are in English! And does anybody knows how I can lock the address bar on English keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Input Language Assistant 2.1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/input-language-assistant/), which "Automatically switches input language to English when you type in address bar."

Answer (score 1):

[Internationalized Domain Names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) - that's why.

For example, [http://موقع.وزارة-الأتصالات.مصر/](http://%D9%85%D9%88%D9%82%D8%B9.%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA.%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1/)